# UITableViewCell in xib as IBOutlet?

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder

Is it safe to setup a UITableViewCell in a xib file, connect it to an IBOutlet property, and return it in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

In theory, I don't see a problem with it assuming the cell in question is **not meant to be reusable**.  In practice, I don't really like doing it this way, but... is there actually a technical problem doing it this way?

```
@interface MyTableViewController()
{
   @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *myCell;
}

....

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        return myCell;
    }

    // else create some other cell manually and return it
}
```

Edit:  I would like to clarify that this is not a stylistic question; I have already decided I am not a fan of this style.  It is simply a question asking if doing it this way can have unforeseen consequences, perhaps if a view is recreated or something.

Comment: As @Aleph7 said, there is no problem with this as long as the cell is only used once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as this cell appears only once in the table, there is no problem with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

There is a big problem with doing it this way because you will only be returning a single cell. Most importantly this would be returning the same cell. The better way to use an nib file to define a tableviewcell is to use the `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` method of UITableView.

[Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerNib%3aforCellReuseIdentifier%3a)

Comment: Didn't see your comment in the bounty. I don't think your solution would cause any problems, but I don't see why you would want to do it differently just because you have a unique cell in the tableview. Registering the nib as I mentioned above works great and the tableview then handles any memory issues you may have.

Comment: Well, it's not necessarily that I WANT to do it this way, but a lot of older code is doing it this way and I'm trying to determine if it is a potential problem, or just a somewhat questionable style choice.

Comment: There is no danger in using "reusable" API for returning "one-time-use" cells. It's even easier to do so, and it consumes the same amount of memory, I suppose.